# Android CameraX. How to change camera parameters after capture start?

Tags: android, android-camera2, android-camerax

I'm working with Android CameraX API. How do I change camera exposure(CONTROL_AE_REGIONS and CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION parameters)?

I found the usage `Camera2Interop.Extender` for sending `CaptureRequests`, but all examples shows how to use it when building camera capture parameters:

```
    val builder = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
    val camera2InterOp = Camera2Interop.Extender(builder)
    camera2InterOp.setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON).setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION, exposure)
    builder.build()
```

How to control capture parameters after camera start? How to change `AE` (or may be send camera requests) **on the fly**?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not possible yet, but fortunately, this will be available in the upcoming releases: https://groups.google.com/a/android.com/g/camerax-developers/c/vnvlYC24vug/m/h0rxYkmUBgAJ

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will wait for the new release.

Answer (score 0):

Both these

```
https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1325716
```

and

```
https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1310574
```

seem to be merged,

Are the changes now available in cameraX.

I want to solve use case of dynamically change camera parameters after start;

Specifically I want to be able to AE LOCK after .build() as below

```
camera2InterOp.setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_LOCK, true)    
val builder = imageAnalyzer.setTargetResolution(Size(480, 360)).build()
```

Any help would be much appreciated